# Unity Initialization Error (mscorlib.dll was not found or could not be loaded) on Android Studio

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

While Running my application on android device and initilizing unity. I'm getting following error :

The assembly mscorlib.dll was not found or could not be loaded.
   It should have been installed in the `/data/app/com.my.package-W99VFUyJj1ncAZ-NhIOmsg==/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll' directory.